# How to redirect to another page if item isn't found in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

In the code below, when $host can't be found in the table I'd like for the page to redirect to another page I set.  I've been struggling for a while to figure out how to do this given the "die(mysql_error())" on the next line.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
$lookup = "SELECT DISTINCT `Id` FROM `google_accountid` WHERE `host_name` = '$host'";
$retailer_query = mysql_query($lookup) or die(mysql_error());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($retailer_query);
if ($num_rows == 0) 
{
header("Location: yourpage.php");
exit();
}
```

Comment: Note that header() only works if it is executed before anything is sent to the browser.

Comment: I get the error: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."  Is this because of the issue you're talking about?  How do I fix this?

Comment: Read the comment above, you may not output ANYTHING prior to changing the header. For example, no "echo", no HTML code, etc etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you could try this:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($retailer_query);
if ($num_rows == 0) header("Location: " . your_new_page);
```

Comment: I get the error: "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by..."  Any idea on how to get rid of it?

Comment: @sharataka: You should put these lines at the very beginning of your page!!

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to check whether the select query returned 0 or more rows, use `mysql_num_rows()`; you do not have to specify any columns in your select statement:

```php
$lookup = "SELECT 1 FROM `google_accountid` WHERE `host_name` = '$host'";
$retailer_query = mysql_query($lookup) or die(mysql_error());
if(mysql_num_rows($retailer_query) === 0)
{
    header("Location: whatever");
    die;
}
```

Alternately, you can use the following example, which allows you to use the returned record at a later stage:

```
$lookup = "SELECT `Id` FROM `google_accountid` WHERE `host_name` = '$host'";
$retailer_query = mysql_query($lookup) or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($retailer_query);
if($row === false)
{
    header("Location: whatever");
    die;
}
echo $row["Id"];
```

`header()` statements should be processed before you send any thing to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($row["Id"] == NULL) {
   header( 'Location: <redirect URL>' ) ;
}
```

Comment: Sorry but for SELECT statements, mysql_query returns an integer resource identifier on success, whether 0 or more rows are returned, or `false` if query failed. It does not return NULL.